# Eigenvector in directed graph

Tags: r, igraph, graph-theory, directed-graph, eigenvector

I want to measure the eigenvector centrality of a directed graph of 262000 nodes and 1M edges in R using igraph package. When i run the command i get this error:

```
> ev<-evcent(amazon,directed=TRUE)
```

> Error in .Call("R_igraph_eigenvector_centrality", graph, directed, scale,  :    At arpack.c:1174 : ARPACK error, Maximum number of iterations reached De plus : Warning message: In .Call("R_igraph_eigenvector_centrality", graph, directed, scale,  : At arpack.c:776 :ARPACK solver failed to converge (1001 iterations, 0/1 eigenvectors converged)

I don't know what mean this error???

Comment: Eigenvector centrality can have issues with directed graphs and asymmetric matrices. (Note the warning in `?eigen_centrality`!) A brief discussion as to way is [here](http://www.sci.unich.it/~francesc/teaching/network/katz.html). Consider other centrality measures for directed graphs like Katz or page rank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means what it says: `Maximum number of iterations reached`.

You can increase the maximum number of iterations. Here is a reproducible example:

First make a graph:

```
> g <- make_ring(1000, directed=FALSE)
```

Then set the default number of iterations to a small number:

```
> arpack_defaults$maxiter = 10
```

Pass that to `eigen_centrality` and get your error:

```
> e = eigen_centrality(g, options=arpack_defaults)
Error in .Call("R_igraph_eigenvector_centrality", graph, directed, scale,  : 
  At arpack.c:944 : ARPACK error, Maximum number of iterations reached
In addition: Warning message:
In .Call("R_igraph_eigenvector_centrality", graph, directed, scale,  :
  At arpack.c:776 :ARPACK solver failed to converge (11 iterations, 0/1 eigenvectors converged)
```

So let's try with more iterations:

```
> arpack_defaults$maxiter = 1000
```

And see if that works:

```
> e = eigen_centrality(g, options=arpack_defaults)
```

No error!

I do not know how large a number of iterations you will need for your graph, or how long it will take. Just keep adding zeroes until it either converges and returns correctly, or you give up because it is taking too long.

Comment: i added the value of `arpack_defaults$maxiter=10000` and still have the same problem, why when we run the **eigen_centrality** in the same dataset with **directed** as **FALSE** we get the response at the same second, and when **directed=TRUE** it's take so much time about 1 hour to get the error.

Comment: There's a note in the help(arpack) that says if the input matrix is symmetric then the computation can be sped up. If directed=FALSE then the adjacency matrix must be symmetric, so perhaps this is the reported speed up. Suggest you investigate with smaller graphs to get a handle on this.